# An error formula for linearization

Tags: calculus, approximation, approximation-theory

> [image]

**Question**: Can anyone shed some light on this formula? I can't find any information on it.

It has three corollaries that I also need to understand:

> [image]

Comment: Anyone...........?

Comment: I believe that it's wrong to claim that provided $E(x)$ satisfies $E(x) = f(x) - L(x)$, but actually $E(x) \approx f(x) - L(x)$ (because there are more terms in the taylor's formula beyond the second term, and to get the exact error you'll have to sum all of them)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a spot light hint for the error formula: It  is simply [Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) for $k=1$.