# Approximating an interval

Tags: calculus, approximation

[image]

[image]

Corollary C is derived from $E_(x) = \frac{f''(x)}{2} \cdot (x-a)^2$

I'm having serious issues understanding this problem and I'm just not getting it right. I'm preparing for a test so this isn't really 'homework' so you can give as hard hints as you want. Thanks!

Comment: Almost identical to: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720513/error-formula-for-linearization/720909#720909

Comment: This is a problem using the same formulas. Apart from the fact that I didn't really receive any answers on my other question. I did however receive a splendid answer on this one so everybody wins.

Comment: I answered your other question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would more visual if it was related to mechanics:

Let $f(x)$ be the position of your car at time $x$, you have initial conditions which are :

- at time $x = 2$, you are at position $4$, that's $f(2) = 4$.
- at time $x = 2$, you are moving with speed $-1$, that's $f'(2) = -1$.
- For any time $x$, you have acceleration in the range $[0, \frac1x]$, that's $0 \le f''(x) \le \frac1x$.

Question is : Where can you be at time $x = 3$?

Comment: Wow, yeah that puts it in a whole new perspective. So all I do is find where I can be with the MINIMUM acceleration and then the MAXIMUM acceleration as dictated by the range!

Thank you so much, that is one of the best answers I have seen!

Comment: Only thing I don't understand is why you say $0 \leq f''(x) \leq 0$

Comment: @Paze : Sorry that's a typo!